# Count Outlook emails/attachments older than 30 days using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, count, outlook

I have mailboxes in Outlook, where I need to count the emails older than 30 days.

I have the following code:

```
Sub HowManyEmails()

Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim EmailCount As Integer

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

On Error Resume Next

Set objFolder1 = objnSpace.Folders("Outlook Data File").Folders("Inbox")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    MsgBox "No such folder."
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each MailItem In objFolder1.Items
    If MailItem.ReceivedTime < (Date - 30) Then EmailCount = EmailCount + 1
Next

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value = EmailCount

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objnSpace = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

`MailItem.ReceivedTime < (Date - 30)` does not work as it should. I think it's because the ReceivedTime in Outlook contains the hour/minute.

Comment: There is no reason why a comparison of a DateTime with the function `Date` should give problems.  Admittedly, if the current date/time is any time on 12 December, the `If` statement will only increment `EmailCount` if the mail was received **before** 12 November, rather than before the current time on 12 November, but it should be at least working close to what you are after.  Why don't you try placing a `MsgBox MailItem.ReceivedTime` just before the `If` statement and see what sort of values you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Items.Restrict Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Then set Filter by Date Diffrent.

Example

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim Filter As String
    Dim DateDiff As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    DateDiff = Now - 30
    Filter = "[SentOn]  < '" & Month(DateDiff) & _
                         "/" & Day(DateDiff) & _
                         "/" & Year(DateDiff) & "'"

    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)

    MsgBox Items.Count & " Items in " & Inbox.Name

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Debug.Print Items(i) 'Immediate Window
    Next
End Sub
```